# R studio crash - C stack trace

Tags: r, crash, rstudio

Lately R studio crashes, seemingly at random. It is therefore difficult to reproduce the code, but I attached the crash screen;

[image: Crash Screen R studio]

As I said, it is very random. In this case it happened when I simply subsetted data, other times it happens in loops, etc. Would anyone what I can do to at least understand what is going on?

Many thanks,
Alex

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rstan_2.21.2         StanHeaders_2.21.0-6 readxl_1.3.1         rstudioapi_0.11      data.table_1.12.8    ggplot2_3.3.2        midasr_0.7           quantreg_5.61        SparseM_1.78        
[10] optimx_2020-4.2      sandwich_2.5-1       loo_2.3.1            quantmod_0.4.17      TTR_0.23-6           xts_0.12-0           zoo_1.8-8           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5          lattice_0.20-41     prettyunits_1.1.1   ps_1.3.3            V8_3.2.0            assertthat_0.2.1    lmtest_0.9-37       R6_2.4.1            cellranger_1.1.0   
[10] backports_1.1.7     MatrixModels_0.4-1  stats4_4.0.2        httr_1.4.2          pillar_1.4.6        rlang_0.4.7         curl_4.3            fracdiff_1.5-1      callr_3.4.3        
[19] texreg_1.37.5       Matrix_1.2-18       checkmate_2.0.0     munsell_0.5.0       compiler_4.0.2      numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 pkgconfig_2.0.3     forecast_8.12       pkgbuild_1.1.0     
[28] urca_1.3-0          nnet_7.3-14         gridExtra_2.3       tibble_3.0.3        codetools_0.2-16    quadprog_1.5-8      matrixStats_0.56.0  fansi_0.4.1         crayon_1.3.4       
[37] conquer_1.0.1       withr_2.2.0         MASS_7.3-51.6       grid_4.0.2          jsonlite_1.7.0      nlme_3.1-148        gtable_0.3.0        lifecycle_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5       
[46] scales_1.1.1        RcppParallel_5.0.2  cli_2.0.2           tseries_0.10-47     timeDate_3043.102   ellipsis_0.3.1      vctrs_0.3.2         Formula_1.2-3       tools_4.0.2        
[55] glue_1.4.1          processx_3.4.3      parallel_4.0.2      inline_0.3.15       colorspace_1.4-1
```

Comment: Does it usually happen when running Stan models?

Comment: Not necessarily. However, I did have some issues lately with stan, which were solved using these steps; https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/rstan-on-windows/16673. You think there might be a link?

Comment: Also, just to clarify. I don't even know what this error means. Note that in the console screen it says "C stack trace" followed by some lines. What is happening? What does this C stack trace mean, and why does it show up in my console screen?

Comment: My thought was to Stan for that same reason; on the post you link to, it says "Stack overflow-like Problems

Your models, particularly if they are non-trivial, might crash or exhibit errors that say things like

    ==== C stack trace ===============================

At the moment, we are not sure if this problem still exists or how to solve it."

Comment: What version of R Studio do you have?

Comment: I am using **R studio 1.3.959**. And many thanks @duckmayr2. I missed that part of the discussion. The link I send was actually not the one I participated in back when I had issues. Again, my code doesn't necessarily crash at the Stan part, so I wasn't immediately thinking of Stan as the main culprit.

Comment: I have a similar problem with **R Studio 1.3.1073** while running `brms::brm()` with  **rstan** and/or **cmdstanr** backend under R 4.0.2 installed on Win 10.

Comment: I found a related thread on [The Stan Forums](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/c-stack-trace-errors/19172). Reinstalling R packages solved the "C stack trace" issue reported there, though I don't think it's the cure-all...